# Creating a project for web assets in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have multiple ASP.NET MVC5 projects that use several similar styles/scripts, and I think, for maintenance's sake, it'd be ideal to have a separate project in Visual Studio 2013 containing the LESS stylesheets and JavaScript files that can be shared between the two.

My setup is as follows:

```
Web.Project1
Web.Project2
Web.Assets //would contain LESS/JS files
Resources
Domain
Data
```

Any pointers?

I've been looking at adding as a link, but I'm not certain that would accomplish what I need.

Comment: may be able to add a reference to the project and include it. Any reason why this would be more maintainable then including the files in a folder? Also don't know how this would play with the whole bundling thing for scripts and css

Comment: I'd probably look at creating a website that serves static content. `static.example.com`

Comment: @Nick - any style changes will need to be reflected on both sites, so it'd be simpler to have one to edit that would affect both. I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049109/net-visual-studio-share-assets-between-projects?rq=1) is similar to mine and I'm going to give that a shot. I'll get back to you.

Comment: What about creating NuGet packages for that content. You can deploy the packages onto a shared folder and configure VS to get packages from there.

Comment: I agree with @JesúsLópez.  We've implemented the same practice in the past where we had many internal business web apps that utilized the same set of assets.  We created a NuGet package for those assets and could easily manage them in one spot.  Then, as the assets were updated/added/etc., deploy a new version of the package and update those apps utilizing the package.

The package would ultimately place the assets in the correct folders within the consuming projects.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through this process for a project of mine, and concluded that if your goal is simply to avoid duplication by keeping your code DRY then using linked files works great.

It's simple enough to do, but I'll write it up anyway as it might save someone some time.

**Quick Summary**

1. Create common *Solution Folders* containing the resources to be shared, or simply designate one of the projects to be the master.
2. Use "Add as Link" to add the shared resource files to each project as needed.
3. Add an *AfterBuild* task to each project file that will copy the linked files to project folders. This is only needed so that Visual Studio test/debug (F5) will work locally.

Detailed explanation follows:

**Configuring Solution Folders for the Shared Resources**

** *Note that if you're simply going to share files directly from one project to one or more additional projects then you can skip this step.*

Visual Studio solution folders do not have to reflect physical file system folders, but doing so will help preserve your sanity. So first create the folders on your local file system and copy the resource files into them. The new folders should be located under your solution folder. For example:

```
\MySolution
   \Common
      \Images
      \Scripts
      \Styles
```

Back in Visual Studio, right click on the *Solution Items* folder and use *Add Solution Folder* to replicate the new file system folders.

Next, add the files to the new solution folders by right-clicking each folder and using *Add Existing Item* to add the contents of the folders.

**Add Shared Resources as Links**

For each project that will use the shared resources, right-click the project folder and choose *Add Existing Item*. Browse to the common folder, select the desired files, click the drop-down arrow next to the "Add" button and choose "Add as Link".

You may get a source control warning about adding files that are outside of the project directory structure, but this can be ignored since the linked file will be under source control at its source.

**Add an *AfterBuild* Task to Copy Files**

When you publish the application to a server the linked files will copied to the project folders to which they are linked and everything works as expected. However, in the development environment the linked files do not physically reside in the project folders. So when you hit F5 to test your application in VS, the shared resources will be missing.

The simple solution is to add an MSBuild task to copy the linked files from their source after each build. This needs to be done to for each project that contains the shared resource links.

Right-click the project and choose *Unload Project*. Right-click the project again and choose *Edit <ProjectFileName>*. Scroll to the bottom and add the following (just above "</Project>"):

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <!-- Copy linked content files to local folders so that they are available in the debugger. 
         This is only an issue when running the application locally. The linked files should 
         be automatically published to the correct folder when publishing to a web server. -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)"
          DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)"
          SkipUnchangedFiles='true'
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles='true'
          Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
  </Target>
```

** *Copy task adapted from [this link](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx).*

Save the project file then right-click and choose *Reload Project*.